# High network latency caused by windows server 2012 R2 computer

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, latency

Okay, so, this is a weird one.

Recently I noticed I’ve been getting extremely high latency (ping) reads, especially when gaming but seemingly in random times, with pings exceeding 2000ms and even 3000ms sometimes. In some cases it would last for a few minutes and sometimes for more than an hour.

I’ve started messing around and replaced the router with no effect. I’ve called up my ISP which then claimed there may be something bad with the infrastructure but nothing can be done about that.

I’ve then decided to tinker more and found out that if I reboot the router in the middle of one of these periods, for a short while the ping is back to normal until it goes back up. I thus concluded that there may be a device in the network causing this and tried turning off my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine I’m running on an old PC. Voila - the high ping was gone as long as the server was off.

There aren’t any new software there or something network-heavy anyway so I doubt it’s the torrent client running there.

Is there an effective way to analyze what is causing the issue and is it actually possible that one device can cause such significant impact on another device on the network?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run Wireshark on the 2012 R2 computer.  When you have the issue, stop capturing and see what sort of traffic it was putting out.

Comment: See answer by sh-beta>>>>>>https://serverfault.com/questions/7913/server-with-slow-ping-response

Comment: Torrent clients can flood a router, see if the issue goes away by stopping all torrents and restart the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Moab suggested, the problem was the torrent client flooded the router even when limited to 200KB/s **upload** rates. I set up lower limits and the problem disappeared.